# How to sort two columns (integer and string)?

Tags: sql, columnsorting

I have a table where the first column is an integer and second column is string. What i wanted is for the first column to sort by sequence first and then second column should group itself one after another when the value is the same. To simulate my idea please see below. Not sure if this even possible?

Sorting 2 columns

[image]

You see the correct order should be as below where the Seq is running in ascending order but when there is same phase it will pick list below it before moving to the next. So the sequence is arrange correctly and yet the grouping of phase also correct

[[image: The correct sequence order i want]

Comment: By the way the sequence from 100, 200, 300, should pair with 1, 2, 3 when the phase value are matched exactly the same

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: i use online database sql [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all)

Comment: Is this a sql question? I'm also not entirely sure I understand your problem, given your comment. Do you want to sort by sequence and then list the phase in order after the sequence? If you sort by sequence, (1,2,3,4,5,6,100,200,300,400,500,600) then the phases will always be listed in that order - as sequence is unique right? (i.e. you can't have two records with sequence 1?) Or do you want to group the phases together and list the records by sequence within the phase? Or, by your latest comment - sort(group) by phase and have records sorted but where order is (1,100,2,200,3,300...)?

Comment: Ok exactly the table should be like this in the sequence order 

* 1 Pilot Hole
* 2 Surface Casing
* 100 Surface Casing
* 3 Intermediate casing
* 200 Intermediate casing

Comment: Ok, so you're sorting by phase altough there is no particular sort order there. "Pilot Hole", "Surface Casing", "Intermediate casing"... is neither ascending or descending alphabetic order. Is there an order there or does it not matter? Would it matter to sort it ascending, say? Then sort the sequences within the phase? Or, have you sorted by sequence to get (1,2), then phase to get (100), then sequence again to get (3), phase to get (200).

Comment: See the new pictures i uploaded in the description "The correct sequence order i want"

Comment: `order by phase, seq`?

Comment: The only way I can see to sort this how you want is to join to your table twice to get the "start from 1" sequence and again to get the "group by name" sequence. Note that you have no explicit sort order in your phase - "P" then "S" then "I" is not alphabetic. This way of sorting is also something I've never seen before and smells a bit wrong. As others have pointed out, a sort by phase then sequence (within phase) is more common. Nevertheless... let's look at how you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be close to what you want:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM PlanActual AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(Seq) AS minSeq, Phase
   FROM PlanActual
   GROUP BY Phase    
) AS t2 ON t1.Phase = t2.Phase
ORDER BY t2.minSeq
```

Comment: +1 That looks right. I had it using Oracle as
 `select t.seq, t.name
  from test t,
       (select min(s1.seq) as seq, s1.name as name from test s1 group by s1.name) s
  where t.name = s.name
  order by s.seq, t.name, t.seq`
The logic being that, as discussed in your question comments, you have to join back to your table to get the overall driving sequence (to get 1,2,3... order; then the phase order that is your real grouping; then your sequence order within the phase).

Comment: YOU F*CKING GENIUS...Thank you so much for saving my life hahaha

Comment: by the way what does the t1 and t2 means how it can be SELECT when it is not even exist in the table? i would appreciate so much your explanation thank you in advance

Comment: @rookie_coder `t1` and `t2` are table *aliases*. We use them to reference the real tables. `t1` is just used for convenience. `t2` is **obligatory** since there is no other way to reference a *derived* table.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos thank you very much for the explanation. You are so amazing!! ...How can i connect with you because i may have plenty of questions in the future about mysql...thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement can be solved by this only

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column1, column2
```

What you fail to understand is the fact that if `column1` is sorted first then `column2` will only be sorted in manner that it does not violate `column1` sorting

consider this table :

```
----------------------------------
empid | empname         | salary |
----------------------------------
200   | Johnson         | 10000  |
----------------------------------
400   | Adam            | 12000  |
----------------------------------
300   | Mike            | 11000  |
----------------------------------
100   | Johnson         | 17000  |
----------------------------------
500   | Tomyknoker      | 10000  |
----------------------------------
```

if you sort by `empid` and `empname`, then output would be like as below

---

```
empid | empname         | salary |
----------------------------------
100   | Johnson         | 17000  |
----------------------------------
200   | Johnson         | 10000  |
----------------------------------
300   | Mike            | 11000  |
----------------------------------
400   |  Adam           | 12000  |
----------------------------------
500   | Tomyknoker      | 10000  |
----------------------------------
```

So here, first, `empid` is sorted as `100, 200, 300, 400, 500`.

Now `empid` `100`corresponds to `Johnson -> 17000` and `200` corresponds to `Johnson -> 10000` , so once empid is sorted, it will try sorting the `empname`

get the idea?

Comment: Yes i have lack of understanding sorry to say...but your sql statement cannot sort it correctly the way i want it refer to question description link "The correct sequence order i want"

Comment: The second one is exactly the way i want it where  the empid is sorted and the empname group the same empname....but the cod your provided does not work on my table

Comment: Its interesting if i use your coding it only sort by seq....and the same phase no longer stand one after another with one another

Comment: didn't get you buddy!

Comment: u see the first pic in the description thats how it looks when using your sql statement SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column1, column2

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword `ASC` or `DESC` after both columns

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
  INNER JOIN (
     SELECT phase,max(seq) as k 
     FROM table 
     GROUP BY phase) keytable 
  using (phase) 
ORDER BY k asc, seq asc
```

Modify the query to match your need

Comment: This is not working it will sort by the seq only and the phase cannot stick together anymore

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table inner join (SELECT phase,max(seq) as k FROM table  group by phase) keytable using (phase) order by k asc, seq asc`


Here I'm using a key, k to sort by phase.

Answer (score 0):

A hack to help towards your sorting goal, maybe you could add a group field to the table so that you can achieve what you want in a cleaner way.

```
SELECT * FROM [PlanActual]
ORDER BY Phase, LEFT(Seq,1)
```